# GitLab Automatic deploy

Tags: git, automation, gitlab

I will be creating a gitlab server at my school to host class code. I wish to make it so that every time any user pushes to gitlab it automatically deploys the project to `/var/www/gitdeploy/<repo-user>/<repo>/<branch>`, in such a way that `http://<myServer>/gitdeploy/<repo-user>/<repo>/<branch>` is accessible.

Preferably it would deploy all branches, but at minimum the master would be fine. All this will be running on the same server.

I heard of Gitlab CI, but wasn't to sure it was for me, and I did not understand how to set it up.

How could I do this?

**EDIT:**
Also, I guess I should specify that I want it for ALL users, hopefully without me configuring it for each user, ice globaly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a possible solution, in the 'Omnibus' install, I believe it is possible to create a global hook by adding some ruby code in `/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/hooks/post-receive`. However, whenever you update gitlab that hook will be reverted to the package version. I would suggest holding the package to avoid this.

Answer (score 4):

You could do it with a git server-side hook (such as `post-receive`) that deploys your code.  Gitlab CI is designed for this, however, and you should consider using it.

If you go with a hook, the hook will be a shell script in `.git/hooks/post-receive/`.  It will need deployment credentials and you will need to write it yourself.  However, that is one use case of hooks.  Check out the documentation: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks

Also see the gitlab-specific documentation: http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/hooks/custom_hooks.html

Comment: I have seen those before, but I was looking for a global solution. (All users)

Comment: Server-side hooks should apply to all users.  They're often used for policy enforcement.

Comment: Ok, I meant ALL Repositories.

Comment: No, I think you have to set it up for each repository, but it will apply to all branches.

Comment: I already have that in place on my own server. Since this will be used for 20+ people, and possibly used after I leave the school, I would prefer it to be automatic for all repos